# Python threading- UDP socket programming

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

Implemented a chat application using UDP sockets that works great, except I can't seem to make two clients chat with each other simultaneously (They are sending and receiving data but not at the same time hence threading).

I'd appreciate good examples of threading because I really can't understand the syntax and how it actually works. It'd be great if the examples are from my problem's perspective- Two clients trying to communicate using two threads separately for receiving and sending.

Comment: Note that threading is not the only (or, in my opinion, even the best) option for this purpose -- the alternative is to use a non-blocking socket and multiplex sending and receiving data via calls to select() or poll().

Comment: I see. For separating send and receive functionalities of my clients(that are communicating with other clients) how would you write a select() or poll() code? People have told me threading is easy but I can't seem to make it work. Could you give me a demo to get me started using your preferred alternative?